# Is there a way to add domains to the whitelist of firebase authentication through CLI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

For Firebase Authentication, when you're to sign in/up on your application, you need to have the host for that app registered as the whitelisted domain in the Firebase Console in order for the operation to proceed.

Is there a way to do this through the firebase cli or some admin sdk of some sort?

I'm trying to deploy an app that uses firebase authentication through kubernetes (GKE). This means for testing, each new deployment's ingress generates a new external IP that needs to be manually added to the whitelisted for the testing to proceed. The deployment is easily automated, but i can't find a way to automate the adding/removing of the IP to the whitelist, or give the whitelist IPs with wildcards, or remove the whitelist.

The domains/whitelist i'm talking about look like the following in the console:
[image: The console at the authentication setting]

and in there:

[image: The whitelist section in the console]

Comment: Is the Firebase Management API what you're looking for?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.webApps#WebApp

Comment: Something like that, but having the feature I need (adding/removing domains from the authentication whitelist), which the APi you linked does not seem to have. The specific page you linked is about the project and the appUrls it talks about are the domains for the apps hosted here, not the domains for the authentication whitelist.

Comment: Then there's probably no way to do what you want.  I suggest filing a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any API to add an authorized domain to Firebase Auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854733/any-api-to-add-an-authorized-domain-to-firebase-auth)

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415910/11865501